# rJava not installing on new laptop

Tags: windows, installation, rjava, jri

Just received a new GTX laptop, and for whatever reason, I am simply not able to install rJava.  No matter what I do with the Java and JDK installs, I get the following message.  I have been uninstalling, rebooting, re-installing, Java (latest versions) and RTools, and yet, I still cannot get rJava to install.

I am using Rstudio as my gui, and I have been able to successfully install rJava on an Ubuntu machine, but for whatever reason, I cannot get this to work on my windows GPU laptop.

I realize this is a question that appears to have been answered in other threads, but I am not seeing the same situation as mine.  Something is different, and I can't figure it out.

What else can I provide to help someone help me?

```
* installing *source* package 'rJava' ...
** package 'rJava' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Generate Windows-specific files (src/jvm-w32) ...
make: Entering directory '/Users/bfcgl/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOcP1l8/R.INSTALLa750514e17ed/rJava/src/jvm-w32'
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/dlltool --as C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/as  --input-def jvm64.def --kill-at --dllname jvm.dll --output-lib libjvm.dll.a
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -O2 -c -o findjava.o findjava.c
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -s -o findjava.exe findjava.o
make: Leaving directory '/Users/bfcgl/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOcP1l8/R.INSTALLa750514e17ed/rJava/src/jvm-w32'
Find Java...
  JAVA_HOME=C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk-14
=== Building JRI ===
  JAVA_HOME=C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk-14
  R_HOME=C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3
JDK has no javah.exe - using javac -h . instead
Creating Makefiles ...
Configuration done.
make -C src JRI.jar
make[1]: Entering directory '/Users/bfcgl/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOcP1l8/R.INSTALLa750514e17ed/rJava/jri/src'
C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk-14/bin/javac -h . -d . ../RList.java ../RBool.java ../RVector.java ../RMainLoopCallbacks.java ../RConsoleOutputStream.java ../Mutex.java ../Rengine.java ../REXP.java ../RFactor.java ../package-info.java
..\Rengine.java:120: error: invalid use of a restricted identifier 'yield'
        while (!alive && !died) yield();
                                ^
  (to invoke a method called yield, qualify the yield with a receiver or type name)
1 error
make[1]: *** [Makefile.all:41: org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.class] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/bfcgl/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOcP1l8/R.INSTALLa750514e17ed/rJava/jri/src'
make: *** [Makefile.all:19: src/JRI.jar] Error 2
**** WARNING: JRI could NOT be built
Set IGNORE=1 if you want to build rJava anyway.
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'
* removing 'C:/Users/bfcgl/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rJava'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Does your ubuntu box use JDK 14 too?

Comment: Not sure.... It's at another location, and due to lockdown.....  Are you suggesting I download the previous version?

Comment: Indeed. Googling around there are some issues raised about javac change that break codes using yield keyword. Ideally you'll want to open an issue on rJava so they'll fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (although installing for the first time on an old laptop) and can confirm that JDK 11 solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I still looking for the same problem resolution, meanwhile, I tried with **Java JDK 11** and I succeed in RStudio. If this helps, try it. I will keep searching for the answer why the new version is not working.

Regards,